# Rescale Dataset using Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to rescale a dataset in using PowerBI Desktop. I've imported a dataset full of raw data, but I can't use row context together with an aggregate. I'm trying to accomplish this:

Data:

```
+---------+-----+
|  Name   | Bar |
+---------+-----+
| Alfred  |   0 |
| Alfred  |  -1 |
| Alfred  |   1 |
| Burt    |   1 |
| Burt    |   0 |
| Charlie |   1 |
| Charlie |   1 |
| Charlie |   0 |
+---------+-----+
```

Calculations:

```
Foo: = SUM(Bar) / COUNT(Bar) GROUP BY Name
```

Which would Generate this dataset:

```
+---------+-----+
|  Name   | Foo |
+---------+-----+
| Alfred  |   0 |
| Burt    |  .5 |
| Charlie | .67 |
+---------+-----+
```

Final Calculation:

```
Score: = (@Foo - MIN(Foo)) / (MAX(Foo)-MIN(Foo))
```

The goal is to grade on a curve with a set of data. I can do it in excel, but was hoping that Power BI could handle all the heavy lifting.

At this point it might be easier to do it all in SQL before bringing it into PowerBI, but that would make it significantly less dynamic (with date filters and the like). Thanks for any insight you might have!

Comment: So your `score` starts @foo but you have'nt defined what you want, whether a sum, max, min,count etc of @foo? As @foo is an array and not a number.

Comment: The goal is to rescale the data based on the highest and lowest value. Lowest gets 0, highest gets 1. @Foo is supposed to represent that particular line (like you would do in Excel). So the update score would be: Alfred=0, Burt=.701754, Charlie = 1

Comment: I presume it is OK to calculate Foo as: `AVG(Bar) GROUP BY NAME` ? Also, your Final Calculation has 2 unclosed right-brackets.  Is it meant to read: `Score: = ( @Foo - MIN(Foo) ) / (MAX(Foo)-MIN(Foo) ) 
` ?

Comment: @MikeHoney I hadn't thought about using an Average. I suppose it gives the exact same values, so that helps. I've added the Right brackets, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the GROUPBY DAX function.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/GROUPBY-Function-DAX-d6d064b2-fd8b-4c1b-97f8-c6d03cdf8ad0

You then would GROUPBY on the Name field and proceed from there.  If need to use the measure outside of a visual that groups by each Name (like show me the average score after applying the curve), then you'll need to wrap that in a calculate table where you include the names, your measure projected as a column, and then do your aggregates (min/max/average) over that calculated table.